# vb.net 2010 append text always at top of a richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I have create a simple function to append text to a Richtextbox. I want that this text is append always on top scrolling the old text to the bottom.

```
Private Sub BoxMessaggio(ByVal testo As String, ByVal errore As Integer)
    Me.ActiveControl = RichTextBox1
    RichTextBox1.Focus()
    If errore Then
        RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red
    Else
        RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black
    End If
    RichTextBox1.AppendText(testo + vbNewLine)
    RichTextBox1.SelectionStart = RichTextBox1.Text.Length
    'RichTextBox1.Select(RichTextBox1.TextLength, 0)
    RichTextBox1.ScrollToCaret()
End Sub
```

I call the function in this way:

```
BoxMessaggio(Now + ": " + ex.Message, 1)
```

I tried a lot of different solutions found here on StackOverflow or in some forums but no one works for me, text is always add at the bottom....

Comment: Does `RichTextBox1.Text = testo & RichTextBox1.Text` work?

Comment: What's the Italian word for _prepend_? Anyone?

Comment: Yes it is works, adding a + vbnewline after testo. Ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treat the `RichTextBox1.Text` as a `String` (because it is), call `Insert`, and place the new text at the front of the strong.

```
RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text.Insert(0, testo + vbNewLine)
```

As for the scrolling. Don't call `Focus` or `ScrollToCaret` and it will stay at the top viewing the most recently added text.

Comment: You're welcome. Also, if it's answers your question, always remember to mark it as such.